# Which storage option is best for my react native application?

Tags: react-native, local-storage, storage

I'm building a React Native application that require to persist some values. But I don't want to trouble setting up backend and cloud databases for simple and small data. The dataset I want to persist is like 81 array items that has boolean values in each.
`[true, true, false .... ]`
OR
`[{id: int, isCompleted: bool}, {id: int, isCompleted: bool},...]`

Since I'm a React web developer and if it is a web application, I would be using local storage. But in React Native, what kind of storage that I can use that's local to the device only?

Comment: `AsyncStorage` should be suitable for this. Android has a 6KB limit (not that you'll reach that) with AsyncStorage but you can increase it if needs be - https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size/#:~:text=Current%20Async%20Storage's%20size%20is,much%20data%20in%20the%20database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best solution in your case is to use AsyncStorage library. Is simple to use and can be stored directly on the device.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

_store = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('array', yourArray);
        } catch (error) {
            // Error
        }
    }

_rertrive = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('array');
            if (value !== null) {
                console.log(value);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Error
        }
    }
```